# Запятая: "стара(,) как мир и Веды"

Tags: запятые

Встретил вот такой отрывок: "Идея Спасения стара, как мир и Веды, и присутствует во всех вероучениях..."

С одной стороны, выражение "стара как мир" — устойчивое, не требующее запятых. Но дополнение "и Веды" устойчивым не является и требует постановки запятой. Как правильно?

В Нацкорпусе есть подобный пример: "Это ― истина старая, как мир и человек". Правила я не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Существует устойчивое выражение ***старо как мир***.

**Старо какъ міръ.**
Ср. Весь этотъ міръ нашъ — это маленькая плесень, которая наросла на крошечной планетѣ. А ты думаешь, что у насъ можетъ быть что-нибудь великое — мысли, дѣло. Все это песчинки. «Да это, братъ, старо какъ міръ!»...Гр. Л. Толстой. Анна Каренина. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/8916/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE

2) Оно встречается в разных вариантах: ***стара как мир, стар как мир,*** при этом в некоторых случаях обособляется, а в других нет (что, скорее всего, зависит от структуры предложения и от расстановки логических ударений):

*Обычное наёмничество, старо как мир! Вещь известная, старо, как мир…

Разбой стар как мир.Принцип стар, как мир: не можешь противостоять движению ― возглавь его.

Сия история стара как мир...Основная мысль книжки банальна и стара, как мир.*

3) Однако при значительном изменении состава оборот обособляется. **Вот и правило:**

**Примечание.** Если имеются некоторые отклонения в употреблении устойчивых оборотов (**порядок слов, подмена слов в устойчивых словосочетаниях** и др.), то выделение возможно: А на мосту, как черт, черный взметнулся плащ (Цвет.). — ср.: черный как черт; Нити древесные... Тают, как дым (Н. Матв.). — ср.: развеялся как дым; при уточнении выделение обязательно: Кто это шагает смело, как герой, в предрассветной темени зимнею порой (Вл. Федоров). — Ср.: сражался как герой. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Comment: "Намосту" — опечатка, раздельно?

Comment: На мосту. Это у них опечатка, пусть тоже исправляют. Спасибо, Артем.

Comment: @Sharon а как определить, является ли прибавление однородного члена к не изменённому устойчивому выражению значительным изменением или нет? Здесь же, ни слова не меняли,ни их порядок. Правило говорит "и др." и добавляет, что выделение только ВОЗМОЖНО, но никак не обязательно. Получается, что выбор в таких вот случаях, как этот, всё равно за автором текста и нет чётких критериев, чтобы однозначно решить обособлять или нет?

Comment: Действительно,  в правилах ПАС говорится, что выделение возможно. Однако в конечном счете всё определяется структурой предложения, а предложение составляет автор. Устойчивые  сравнительные обороты имеют небольшой объем и занимают в предложении позицию наречия. А что это значит? Это значит, что ударение в сочетании глагол (прилагательное) + оборот падает на оборот, пауза отсутствует.  Но чем больше мы  распространяем оборот,, тем сложнее обеспечить такое прочтение. Особенно ясно мы это видим на примере  "истина стАрая, как мир и человЕк".

Comment: Здесь используется полное прилагательное, и прочитать это сочетание удобно  только с двумя ударениями. А это обозначает наличие паузы и обособление оборота.  Что касается первого предложения, то там такая расстановка ударений: Идея Спасения старА, как мир и ВЕды, и присУтствует во всех вероучениях… Здесь ударением выделены ОДНОРОДНЫЕ сказуемые, а из этого следует обособление оборота. Поэтому Розенталь предупреждает нас, что нельзя подходить к этой теме формально, каждое предложение индивидуально и имеет свое решение. Правила же дают нам общий ориентир при решении задачи.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо. Идеальное объяснение. Я даже считаю, что его стоило бы внести в ответ.